# C# - Convert date to unix timestamp

Tags: c#, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert the date `Saturday, 22. October 1932 00:00:00` to the unix timestamp `-1173747600000`.

My code here:

```
DateTimeOffset dt2 = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1932, 10, 22)).ToUniversalTime();
long a = dt2.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

I am getting the timestamp `-1173751200000`. What are I doing wrong?

[Epochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/) is calculating as expected the unix timestamp. See local time option and then Timestamp in milliseconds

Comment: From **Remarks** in **[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2)** `For date and time values before 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, this method returns a negative value.`

Comment: Yes, ok no problem. I am working with negative value.

Answer (score 4):

You're forgetting the time zone. The only time zone where `22 October 1932 00:00` equals `-1173747600000` is [UTC-01:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9201:00)

There isn't any way in .NET (that I can find) to create a `DateTime` in a time zone other than local or UTC, so you have to just subtract an hour (from UTC), which takes you to `21 October 1932 23:00 UTC`:

```
var date = new DateTime(1932, 10, 21, 23, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dt2 = new DateTimeOffset(date);
long a = dt2.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

That results in `-1173747600000`.

Comment: Calling ToUniversalTime() is not necessary here. ToUnixTimeMilliseconds method first converts the current instance to UTC

Comment: @Alex Very true. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first clue is the difference in the timestamps: they're 3600 seconds apart, or in other words one hour. My guess is that there's a daylight savings issue coming in to play.

You can see that this is being applied by DateTimeOffset by looking at the properties of the object. Using it in Powershell:

```
$t = [datetime]::Parse("1932-10-22")
new-object system.datetimeoffset($t)
```

gives output:

```
DateTime      : 22/10/1932 00:00:00
UtcDateTime   : 21/10/1932 23:00:00
LocalDateTime : 22/10/1932 00:00:00
Date          : 22/10/1932 00:00:00
Day           : 22
DayOfWeek     : Saturday
DayOfYear     : 296
Hour          : 0
Millisecond   : 0
Minute        : 0
Month         : 10
Offset        : 01:00:00
Second        : 0
Ticks         : 609618528000000000
UtcTicks      : 609618492000000000
TimeOfDay     : 00:00:00
Year          : 1932
```

`DateTimeOffset.ToUniversalTimeMilliseconds()` returns the unix-time from the UTC value of the datetime.

So you need to create the DateTimeOffset with the UTC timezone instead, so (again with PS, but it's trivial to convert to C#)

```
$t = [datetime]::Parse("1932-10-22")^C
$ofs = new-object System.Timespan(0)
new-object system.datetimeoffset($t, $ofs)
```

Gives:

```
DateTime      : 22/10/1932 00:00:00
UtcDateTime   : 22/10/1932 00:00:00
LocalDateTime : 22/10/1932 01:00:00
Date          : 22/10/1932 00:00:00
Day           : 22
DayOfWeek     : Saturday
DayOfYear     : 296
Hour          : 0
Millisecond   : 0
Minute        : 0
Month         : 10
Offset        : 00:00:00
Second        : 0
Ticks         : 609618528000000000
UtcTicks      : 609618528000000000
TimeOfDay     : 00:00:00
Year          : 1932
```

Now this gives an millisecond epoch timestamp of -1173744000000, which is different to the value you're expecting. I've checked a couple of sources, including epochconvertor.com and this does appear to be the correct time. The timestamp you've provided, -1173747600000, is 21 Oct 1932 at 23:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX timestamp is the number of seconds that passed since 1. 1. 1970. That is why you get a negative number for a date that preceds it.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am getting negative number because the date is before 1.1.1970. But if I get -1173751200000 instead -1173747600000, it works. Why epochconverter interprets right the negative duration?